# Erro ao instalar o Mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estou tentando instalar o mariadb e o sistema retorna o seguinte erro
A minha pergunta é a seguinte, como instalar em um diretório sem ser o /var/cache...

[image: Erro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Imagem indica que está sem espaço, precisa limpar ele:

Primeiro, verifique /tmp está vazio.

Em seguida, tente vincular o espaço de **`/home`** para **`/var/cache/yum/base/packages`**

```
mount --bind /home/yum /var/cache/yum/base/packages
```

Em seguida, adicione uma entrada na parte **`/etc/fstab`** assim:

```
/home/yum /var/cache/yum/base/packages none,rw bind 0 0
```

depois que tiver feito isso, rode: `df -h` ele mostrará `/var/cache/yum/base/packages`

com isso você poderá tentar instalar novamente